# Platform support in the Crystal Clemmys release

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which platforms (OS versions + CPU architectures) are planned to be supported in the ROS2 'Crystal Clemmys' release?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301414/platform-support-in-the-crystal-clemmys-release/) by [leej](https://answers.ros.org/users/37137/leej/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At some point the REP 2000 will be updated to define these.

For now I would expect that Crystal will target the same platforms as Bounce since there are no new platforms (not considering non-LTS Ubuntu distros) - see http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#bouncy-bolson-june-2018-june-2019.

The exact minimum versions for dependencies will likely be updated for the rolling platforms like macOS and Windows.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0